# How can I update a whole array in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to replace an array in my object with a whole new array, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Here is my query:

```
Supply.update({_id: ObjectId('5e767d23d6d4390b6468b27c')}, {$set: {supplyList: req.body.pickupInfo.supplyList}});
```

Supply is equal to:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const supplySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    email: String,
    address1: String,
    address2: String,
    zipCode: Number,
    supplyDescription: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    suppliesNeeded: String,
    paymentType: String,
    dateSubmitted: String,
    ipAddess: String,
    supplyList: [
        {
            name: String,
            pickedUp: Boolean
        }
    ]
});
const collectionName = 'supplies'
module.exports = mongoose.model('Supply', supplySchema, collectionName);
```

And my database has this in it: 
[DB Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLyzm.png)

I'm trying to replace supplyList with a whole new supply list array that will look like this:

```
    [
  { name: 'test', pickedUp: false },
  { name: 'test', pickedUp: true },
  { name: 'dfasdf', pickedUp: true },
  { name: 'asdf', pickedUp: false }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$push`

```
 db.collectionName.update (
   {
      $push: {
        supplyList: {
          $each: [{name:"test", pickedUp: false}, {name:"test", pickedUp:true}, {name:"dfasdf", pickedUp:true}, {name:"asdf", pickedUp: false}]
       }
      } 
   });
```